# process builder check if two days and return true/false

Tags: process-builder, formula

I'm trying to compare if the two dates <= 30 if yes then returning the true or false

Here is my formula that I'm using:

```
If(!ISBLANK( Cancel_Date__c  ),  Cancel_Date__c ,
If(MOD(( Date_Executed__c + 4) - date(1900, 1, 7), 7) <= 30,  
Date_Executed__c + 5, Date_Executed__c + 4))
```

The error I'm getting:

> The formula expression is invalid: Formula result is data type (Date),
> incompatible with expected data type (true or false).

Process Builder:

`flag__c` is a checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are returning dates from your conditions instead of true/false as you say you'd like to do.

The [syntax](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) is

`IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

As noted in the doc,

> replace value_if_true with the value you want returned if the expression is true; replace value_if_false with the value you want returned if the expression is false.

What you are currently doing is:

1. If `Cancel_date__c` is not blank, return the value of `Cancel_Date__c` (which I'm assuming is a date field).
2. In your next IF statement you're returning `Date_Executed__c` + 5 or `Date_Executed__c` + 4 which are also not true/false values.

I'm, again, making assumptions you're talking about 30 days between `Cancel_Date__c` and `Date_Executed__c`, but you can hopefully understand why you receive the error message.

Notes

1. You can add conditions to your action group if one of them being blank means you shouldn't evaluate or means you shouldn't set the field. You can have multiple action groups to set the field to whatever default it should be if a field is null.
2. If my assumptions are correct, I'm not seeing any reason it can't be as simple as subtracting the two dates in your if conditions. You'll have to handle null conditions, but that depends on the scenarios and whether the Action Group filters can help.

```
IF(Cancel_Date__c - Executed_Date__c <= 30, true, false)
```